# in javascript how to call a function inside another function block?

Tags: javascript

How to call `startSendingWork` from below context?

```
'use strict';

const
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    zmq = require('zmq'),
    self = this;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    let
        masterWorkPusher = zmq.socket('push').bind('ipc://master-push.ipc'),
        masterResultsPuller = zmq.socket('pull').bind('ipc://master-pull.ipc'),
        numWorkersAlive = 0,
        masterResultsPuller.on('message', function(data){
            if (data.message == 'ready') {
                numWorkersAlive++;
                if (numWorkersAlive == 3) {
                    self.startSendingWork(masterWorkPusher); // UNRESOLVED FUNCTION how to call startSendingWork???
                }
            } else if (data.message == 'result') {
                console.log(data.result);
            }
        });

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else { // not master

}

function startSendinWork(masterWorkPusher) {
    console.log("sending 30 jobs...");
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        masterWorkPusher.send({message: "do_some_work"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have the .self in front of the method call? Also put the function above the other code to make sure it's defined before it's called.

Comment: A typo? The method name lacks "g" in Sending.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks fixed :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla if you post as answer i'll accept.

Comment: @Jas: question with typos are usually closed/deleted, they don't introduce much value to further readers. I am glad anyway that this was the fix you needed, regards.

Comment: @Oisin moving a function to the top is unnecessary in this situation due to variable hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a typo as Wiktor said was defined as startSendinWork

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to invoke function in javascript.

```
functionName();
functionName.call(context, args);
functionName.apply(context, args[])
```

Note before call the function, make sure that it is defined .
In your case you are trying to call function which is not yet defined .

Comment: It is defined.  It is public in the very same scope as the code that calls it.